# Managing objects returned from C++ function

Tags: c++

I am wondering how one would go about returning a new object from a C++ function. For example, I have a SQLite wrapper which used to mix in Objective-C and I modifying it to be purely C++.

So, for example:

```
list<char*> * SqliteWrapper::RunQuery(const char *query)
{
       list<char*> * result = new list<char*>();

       //Process query

       return result;
}
```

the issue that I can see in this, is that who owns the object? The calling class or the class that created the object? What is worse, is that this is very prone to memory leaks. If the caller object does not delete the newly created object, the app will end up with a memory leak.

Now that I think about this, this would make a lot of sense:

```
int SqliteWrapper::RunQuery(const char *query, list<char*>& result)
{
       //Process query

       return errorCode;
}
```

Are there any other approaches to this? I have been a C# programmer for a while and only now am starting to work heavily with C/C++.

Comment: Change it to return a `std::list<std::string>`. I'd also take a `std::string` as the query.

Comment: You might use shared pointer, shared_ptr. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer

Comment: I hope my answer was sufficient, give me a comment if not.

Comment: There's no hard and fast rule. An object should be owned by whatever makes most sense in each particular case. In your case it's natural for code that creates the query (i.e. the caller of RunQuery) to own the result. It's why the query is created in the first place. Note it's perfectly OK for RunQuery to allocate the result and return the pointer to its rightful owner. You may want to use shared_ptr or unique_ptr, or probably return by value (it is not expensive as the compiler will most certainly elide the copy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many programmers do this:

If it is a pointer that is returned, I am being given the object's identity (it's location in memory is unique) I must manage that. I am responsible for deleting it.

(Pointer = my job)

references however let you pretend you are being passed the object, to look at and use. you are not responsible for deleting these, something else is.

BUT:

"Naked pointers" may be frowned upon for code like this (it's very subjective) so some would say use a "unique_ptr" to that, these can be moved, and delete what they point to when deleted (unless the stuff is moved out of them), by returning one and not using it, it will be deleted.

(tell me if you want me to flesh this out, see also "shared_ptr" if multiple things have a pointer, this will delete what it points to when the last shared_ptr pointing to it is deleted)

**Addendum 1**

```
unique_ptr<list<char*>> SqliteWrapper::RunQuery(const char *query)
{
       list<char*> * result = new list<char*>();

       //Process query

       return make_unique<list<char*>>(result);
}
```

Remember you can only move, not copy unique_ptrs

Comment: Apologies for a stupid question. For unique pointers, the unique pointer is passed in? Or is the function responsible for returning one?

Comment: @SergueiFedorov `unique_ptr<T>`'s destructor deletes whatever it was pointing to, but when you move a `unique_ptr<T>` into another one (like `unique_ptr<T> result = myFunction();`)the unique_ptr returned has it's contents (a pointer) moved out into "result", now result has the ptr, and the thing returned has null, delete on null does nothing. When result goes out of scope (unless moved out) result's destructor will delete the T* it has.

Comment: Thank you very much for your informative answer. This really clears things up!

Answer (score 0):

Well. You are right.

First example would be a bad style, since in such a code is hardly readable and it is hard to track bugs in it.

Usually people use the second approach with reference.
In the same way you can use pointer, allocating the return object before function call.

Third approach would be to use class instead of function. It is convinient if your function does complicated process with many parameters. In this case you store result as a data member of the class and ownership is obvious:

```
class SqliteWrapper {
...
  class ProcessQuery {
    public:
      ProcessQuery():fQ(0),fP1(0){}
      SetQuery(const char *query){ fQ = query; }
      SetP1(int p1){ fP1 = p1; }
      ...

      list<char*> GetResult(){ return fR; } // copy

      int Run();
    private:
      const char *fQ;
      int fP1;
      ...

      list<char*> fR;
  }
...
}

int SqliteWrapper::Process::Run()
{
  //Process query

  return errorCode;
}
```

Comment: It still has a copy and stuff in it. This object can have various states and relies on a copy. I shall edit my answer.

Comment: What is the alternative if the process task is huge?

Comment: See my answer. Please put @alecteal in stuff directed at me. I don't like yours because you try to impose a `ProcessStructure` and stuff, he is wondering about memory management, and I think that's a very... nasty way of interacting with a database (what you put) no offence of course. It's very late, I promise I will clarify further tmorrow.

Comment: @alecteal, your answer is still function based. In my opinion it would be unreadable if such a function has to be like 10000 lines of code or the process has to be divided on 20 subfunctions and take 20 optional parameters.

Comment: But still better than the factory implementation with a copy you created. There'd also be nothing wrong with function calls in a function. If you are not using virtuals, you can convert to a "C" like form very easily (T::myMethod(A,B,C) --> myMethod(T*,A,B,C) and you can even name T* "this" - I am not saying do this, but as you can see it's not a totally different implementation.)